# Grouping by in Java 8 stream to custom class rather than the origin class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a class A which has some fields.

```
Class A{
 String type;
 String x;
 String y;
}

Class B{
    String x;
    String y;

}
```

Let's say we have a list `List<A>`. By using `Collectors.groupingBy()` , is it possible to get output `Map<String,List<B>>` instead `Map<String,List<A>>`  ? where `key` in the `Map` is `type` field in `Class A`.

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(..., Collectors.mapping(....))`

Answer (score 1):

Of course - just chain a `mapping()` collector to the `groupingBy()` collector.

```
Map<String,List<B>> map =
    listA.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getType,
                                        Collectors.mapping(a->new B(a.getX(),a.getY()),
                                                           Collectors.toList())));
```