# Java Stream Convert List to Map of Integer-Set

Tags: list, java-8, set, maps, java-stream

I have a `List<StructureA>`.

Now this structure comprises of a `Type`: *typeA* & *typeB*.
Type here is an Enum.

StructureA comprises of fields : countryCode, Type, timeZone.
StructureB comprises of fields: countryCode, timeZone

I want to convert this List into a `Map<Type, Set<StructureB>>`. Is this possible using streams?

Comment: What is the relationship between `StructureA` and `Type` ?

Comment: What is the data type of `Type`?

Comment: StructureA has multiple attributes e.g. timeZone, countryCode, type etc. Type here is an enum, which can either be typeA or typeB.

Comment: Related/duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110564/grouping-by-in-java-8-stream-to-custom-class-rather-than-the-origin-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use grouping by collector

```
Map<Type, Set<StructureB>> collect = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StructureA::getType,
                Collectors.mapping(a -> new StructureB(a), Collectors.toSet())));
```